# Java Thread.sleep() Cant Works Properly ,Why?

Tags: java

Below my code Gives me strange Results, Obviously you must be getting `1000`, but in reality do not expect anything below 3500. I got 3500-4500 on different runs. And I read some where that Thread.sleep is completely unreliable. Why does java not **Depcrecate** it, if its useless?

Is There Any solution For that?

```
class MyClass {

            public static void main ( String[] args ) {

                    long start, end, took;

                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    for ( int i=0; i<200; i++) {
                            try {
                            Thread.sleep (5);
                            } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    System.out.println("Start :: " + start);
                    System.out.println("end :: " + end);
                    took = end -start;
                    System.out.println ("Took: " + took);

            }
```

Comment: What platform & JDK/JRE are you using? Getting more than 1000 is expected (up to 2000-3000 range seems very reasonable). (BTW, I'm getting 1010-1020 consistently here.)

Comment: Start :: 1330464140994
end :: 1330464142016
Took: 1022

here is my result, nothing seems strange

Comment: Please use [System.nanoTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) for measuring code execution.

Comment: JDK 7 new java 7 with Eclipse indigo ....Why Minus vote?

Comment: Within eclipse? Are you sure you don't have a debugger plugged in to that VM that might, maybe, skew the timings a bit?

Comment: Its not useless, but it is OS dependant because it gets the OS to do the sleeping.  What would you replace it with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precise timing in `Thread.sleep` is not guaranteed and that's precisely the reason you're getting different timings on different runs.

Better to use [RealTimeThread](http://www.rtsj.org/specjavadoc/javax/realtime/RealtimeThread.html) for real time calculation in Java.

Comment: To use real-time thread you need Real Time Java on real time operating system. See here: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp Most applications don't need precise timing calculation and hence are happy with Thread.sleep calculations.

Comment: because java realtime only works on specific versions of solaris and linux :)

Answer (score 4):

It does exactly what it says, which is sleep for *at least* 5 milliseconds.  Nothing guarantees it won't wait longer, it never claims to.  (admittedly the javadoc on the method can give the impression that the thread will promptly resume, in reality this is up to operating system/jvm and you have no control over it.)

It is certainly strange that it takes 3-4 seconds to run.  Depends on your platform/operating system and what else your computer may be doing at the time.  I get results between 1010 and 1020 running that exact code snippet.  Is that what you're actually running or did you extract that as an example from a larger program?

Older versions of windows have around a minimum 15ms sleep by default, which would explain values over 3 seconds.  Some JVMs tinker with windows to get better sleep resolution, but for any specific combination of JVM version and OS version, tough to say!

Answer (score 0):

It is not that it is useless, it is just that you have to use it with caution, and not expecting consistent results, since again *with threads very little is guaranteed.*

Answer (score 0):

If you need some kind of Timer a low level Thread is not the right thing. A Thread make use of the underlaying OS Scheduler to distribute CPU Time to the Processes of the System. Infact the JavaVM also spawns Processes and a Thread is fed with CPU Time by a JavaVM Scheduler.

When you switch a thread into the state of sleeping you have to wait until the Scheduler wake you up again.

If you need accurate Timing take a look at TimerTask and Timer